# How to put few custom controls dynamicaly inside a datatemplete on Mouse behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, listbox, datatemplate

I have a Datatemplete for List-box Item in which I have a Grid with two columns using WPF. In the first column I want to put few customized controls(Buttons) dynamically using C# in code behind. I don't know how to start and from where should I start, can anybody please help me with some great inputs and examples. Any answer will be greatly appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

XAML code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxItem"
                     Grid.Row="1"
                     SelectionMode="Extended"
                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                     VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
                     VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                     FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                     KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
                     Background="DarkGray"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding}">

                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                        <WrapPanel x:Name="ListContent"
                                   IsItemsHost="True"
                                   Width="500"/>

                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>

                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center">

                            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                        Width="30"
                                        Height="{Binding Height}">
                               <--Here I want to put few customize buttons in code behind-->
                            </StackPanel>

                            <Image x:Name="MainPage" 
                                   Stretch="UniformToFill"
                                   Source="{Binding ImagePath}"
                                   Height="{Binding Height}"
                                   Width="{Binding Width}"/>

                        </DockPanel>

                </DataTemplate>

            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for adding Controls inside a the First column of your grid then put a Panel inside the first column and in code behind add controls as child to that Panel. So as you mentioned in above that you are using DataTemplete then I would like to say that you can access that Panel something like:

Put the below codes inside the event where you wnt to add the controls.

```
ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)(this.lst.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i));
ContentPresenter presenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(item);
DataTemplate template = presenter.ContentTemplate;
StackPanel stack = (StackPanel)template.FindName("FirstColumn Panel Name", presenter);
```

and then call the below method:

```
private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
where childItem : DependencyObject
{
       for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
       {
               DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
               if (child != null && child is childItem)
                     return (childItem)child;
               else
               {
                     childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
                     if (childOfChild != null)
                          return childOfChild;
               }
        }
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already resolved this issue something like this way only.

Answer (score 2):

You specified wanting to use code behind, so it would look something like this:

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Initialized="StackPanel_Initialized" .. />
```

Code behind:

```
using MyNamespace;

private void StackPanel_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyControl newItem = new MyControl();
    // Set any other properties

    StackPanel parent = sender as StackPanel;
    parent.Children.Add(newItem);
}
```

Comment: Hi Rachel, thanks a lot for your answer. If you will not mind can you please share an article which will tell me how this Initialized event for StackPanel works.

Comment: @SharpUrBrain Here's a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.initialized.aspx. I used Initialized instead of Loaded since Initialized is only run once (during initiation) while Loaded can get run multiple times, but you can switch to Loaded if you  need to. For example, a TabControl runs Loaded/Unloaded when you switch tabs

Comment: @Rachel: If I say, I want to add the controls at MouseHover time on selected ListBoxItem and MouseLeave from Selected ListBoxItem then what will you suggest me to do ?

Comment: @SharpUrBrain You could use the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events instead, although personally I would probably build a `ContentControl` with a trigger that switches the `Template` based on the `IsMouseOver` property since then you are not constantly recreating items

Comment: @Rachel: actually I am not able to give you clear picture about my problem and again I am not able to solve this problem on mouseHover or MouseEnter, So if you don't mind then can you please share sample code of your application what you did? I think I may find some help from it.

Comment: @SharpUrBrain I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for. Take the code you have in your Question, add the Initialized event to the StackPanel where you are trying to add your custom buttons, then in the CodeBehind copy my code. Replace the MyNamespace and MyControl with your own objects and when you run the program you should see your custom buttons added to the ListBoxItem.

Comment: @Rachel: Thanks for your great efforts, I accomplished this issue by using the FindVisualChild method something like the below sample given by Turtleneck